# Unable to save image in object in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have class `Person` in which I have some properties such as:

```
@property NSString *name;
@property NSString *email;
@property NSString *phone;
@property UIImage *image;
@property NSInteger *id;
@property NSString *date;
```

I am saving value like this:

```
Person *person = [[Person alloc] init];
person.name=@"john";
person.email=@"john@gmail.com";
person.phone=@"1123124";
person.id=@"345";
person.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.png"];
```

When I get the value I am able to get all values like name, email, phone etc. But I am not able to get the value of the `image`. I am getting `nil` value for `image`. Why can't I save the value of `image` in my `Person` class?

Comment: You are using `@property NSString *image;` change it to `@property UIImage *image;`

Comment: Sorry i typed wrong i am using UIImage Already @0yeoj

Comment: Don't type it, copy and paste it. Always post real code. BTW - You need to specify `copy` or `strong` for all of your object properties. And your `id` property should be `NSInteger`, not `NSInteger *`. And don't use `id` as a name. It is confusing with the `id` keyword.

Comment: It sounds like it can't find the image named pic.png

Comment: make sure `pic.png` exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that your program is unable to find the image named `pic.png`.